# Heterogeneous array that conforms to protocol with associated type in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

I have a protocol `AProtocol` with an associated type `AType` and a function `aFunc`. I want to extend `Array` such that it conforms to the protocol by using the result of its elements `aFunc` function. Clearly this is only possible if elements of the array conform to `Aprotocol` and have the same associated type so I have set this toy example:

```
protocol AProtocol {
    associatedtype AType
    func aFunc(parameter:AType) -> Bool
}

extension Array : AProtocol where Element : AProtocol, Element.AType == Int {
    func aFunc(parameter: Int) -> Bool {
        return self.reduce(true, { r,e in r || e.aFunc(parameter: parameter) })
    }
}

extension String : AProtocol {
    func aFunc(parameter: Int) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

extension Int : AProtocol {
    func aFunc(parameter: Int) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

This works fine for arrays which contain only one type:

```
let array1 = [1,2,4]
array1.aFunc(parameter: 3)
```

However for heterogeneous arrays, I get the error `Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional` and then `Value of type '[Any]' has no member 'aFunc'` if annotate it as follows:

```
let array2 = [1,2,"Hi"] as [Any]
array2.aFunc(parameter: 3)
```

Is it possible to extend Array as I wish such that heterogeneous arrays are allowed so long as they conform to `AProtocol` and have the same `AType`?

Comment: i guess your requirement need to be an array of different types

Comment: @Sh_Khan, What do you mean specifically?

Comment: The shortest answer on the last question is no.

Comment: @BenJacob See if the updated answer meets your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this fits your needs.

## Approach:

Remove the associated type

## Implementation:

```
protocol BProtocol {
    func aFunc(parameter: BProtocol) -> Bool
}

extension String : BProtocol {
    func aFunc(parameter: BProtocol) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

extension Int : BProtocol {
    func aFunc(parameter: BProtocol) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}

extension Array : BProtocol where Element == BProtocol {

    func aFunc(parameter: BProtocol) -> Bool {
        return self.reduce(true, { r,e in r || e.aFunc(parameter: parameter) })
    }
}
```

## Invoking:

```
let a1 : [BProtocol] = [1, 2, 3, "Hi"]

let boolean = a1.aFunc(parameter: 1)
```